# saving the number into the variable in every run of cycle python

Tags: python

I wrote the function that converts the string in argument to number. If the string does not contain number the cycle breaks and the new variable with numbers is printed. 
If the argument is "123" the function returns 6. I don't want to return the sum, just placing every number in a row. How do I accomplish the result 123? I don!t know what to use instead of string2 += float(c).

```
def try_parse(string):
 string2=0
 for c in string:
  if c.isdigit() == True: 
   string2 += float(c)
  else:
    break 
 return string2
```

Comment: Try and think about what the `1` then means in the input. That's not `1`, that's really `100`. And what does the `1` in `12` mean? Again, that's not a `1`, that's `10`, really.

Comment: Each time you find a new digit, the preceding digits are 1 order of magnitude *larger*.

Comment: Are you trying to check if something is a number, or convert it to a number?

Comment: I wanna convert the input to number, but when for example input is like: 123.5hgp the result should be 123.5 and the hgp is ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code:

```
def try_parse(string):
    string2 = ""
    for c in string:
        if not c.isdigit() and c != '.':
            break
        string2 += c
    return string2
```

You can see that now I use string2 as a string and not an int (When the `+` sign is used on an int you sum, and with a string `+` is used for concatenation).

Also, I used a more readable `if` condition.

**Update:**

Now the condition is ignoring the `'.'`.

Tests:

```
>>> try_parse('123')
'123'
>>> try_parse('12n3')
'12'
>>> try_parse('')
''
>>> try_parse('4.13n3')
'4.13'
```

**Note**

The return type is **string** you can use the [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) function wherever you like :)

Comment: I see but what if I want to process also float numbers like 123.5n3 float(c) returns 123.0 and the decimal is lost

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a string for `string2`, and `str` instead of `float`.

You want `string2 = ""`, and `string2 += c`. (You don't need to call `str` on `c` because it is already a string.)

Answer (score 0):

You could leave the conversion to a number to Python (using `int()`, rather than `float()`; you only filter on digits), and only worry about filtering:

```
def try_parse(string):
    digits = []
    for c in string:
        if c.isdigit():
            digits.append(c)
    return int(''.join(digits))
```

but if you really want to build a number yourself, you need to take into account that digits are not just their face value. `1` in `123` does not have the value of one. It has a value of 100.

The easiest way then to build your number would be to multiply the number you have *so far* by 10 before adding the next digit. That way `1` stays `1`, and `12` starts as `1` then becomes `10` as you add the `2`, etc:

```
def try_parse(string):
    result = 0
    for c in string:
        if c.isdigit():
            result = result * 10 + int(c)
    return result
```